# Colapse even rows of table

Tags: theming

I have a table in my site that I build in my own module with theme table. I want to be able to have a sort of link in each even row (the ones with the color buttons) that allows me to collapse those rows. In fact, when loading the page, those rows should be already collapsed and only visible if the user wants.

[image]

Is this even possible using theme table? Is there any alternative I should use to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ctools_collpasbile is a solution? http://timonweb.com/posts/painless-collapsible-divs-in-drupal/#

I just can't apply it to my table.